# How do I extract a .jpg or .png from a website using a zoom window

Tags: http

I'm trying to download an image from this website:
http://digitalcollections.tcd.ie/home/index.php?DRIS_ID=MS58_003v
from their digitization of the Book of Kells.  They obviously want to share the images with the world.  My problem is that when I right-click to save image, all I get is a portion of the image about 750 by 950 pixels.  If I wanted to, I could screen shot it, segment by segment and then assemble it all in MSPaint, but that is tedious and I might not get the re-allignments right.  So, my question is, "How do I get a nice, complete .png image from that website, even though they are using a zoom window?"
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: why not write email to them and ask how to download the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most detailed images have the URL like this:

http://digitalcollections.tcd.ie/content/14/pages/MS58_001r/image_files/12/0_0.jpg

which goes up to `9_12`.

The `MS58_001r` is `MS58_00` followed by the page's "name" which you can extract using:

```
$(".toc_page_number").each(function (index, element) {
   console.log(element.textContent.split(" ")[1]);
});
```

You can easily create a script in python which generates all the links and downloads them, and using [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html#cutting-pasting-and-merging-images) you can [stitch them together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34301747/865175).

Comment: Thanks, man.  You've pointed me in the right direction.  I'm more of a C# kind of guy, so looks like I have to learn a bit of Python.  I see that there is no oversized .jpeg to use anyway.  It's all a patchwork, I guess to avoid monster download times.

Comment: I think it's because it offers high detail zooming option. So if you zoom to the maximum level, you only see a portion of it, so there's no reason to download the entire high detailed zoomed image, so it uses a bunch of tiles. This is probably the same reason and method Google Maps does it too.