# Stitching two 100 KB Images in Python's Pillow results in a 150 MB output image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need to stitch 2 images together in Python.
I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657383/stitching-photos-together) (code below), and it stitches them fine, but I ran into a problem:
My source TIFF images are ~100 KB each, but my output image is ~150 MB.
Why is it happening, and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

```
from PIL import Image

def merge_images(file1, file2):
    """Merge two images into one, displayed side by side
    :param file1: path to first image file
    :param file2: path to second image file
    :return: the merged Image object
    """
    image1 = Image.open(file1)
    image2 = Image.open(file2)

    (width1, height1) = image1.size
    (width2, height2) = image2.size

    result_width = width1 + width2
    result_height = max(height1, height2)

    result = Image.new('RGB', (result_width, result_height))
    result.paste(im=image1, box=(0, 0))
    result.paste(im=image2, box=(width1, 0))
    return result
```

Comment: Possibly the input images were compressed, but you're saving the result in an uncompressed format.  What are the actual dimensions of the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Image.save() without supplying additional arguments will save the image in TIFF format without using compression.

Have a look under Saving TIFF Images in the Pillow documentation for the different compression options available

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html?highlight=writer

From Saving TIFF Images

> **compression**
>       A string containing the desired compression method for the file. (valid only with libtiff installed) Valid compression methods are: None, "tiff_ccitt", "group3", "group4", "tiff_jpeg", "tiff_adobe_deflate", "tiff_thunderscan", "tiff_deflate", "tiff_sgilog", "tiff_sgilog24", "tiff_raw_16"

For example you could save the resultant image with:

```
result.save('result.tiff', compression="tiff_deflate")
```

Comment: Thank you!
With deflate alone, the result has already shrunk to 1.13MB.